# /world frame in stage simulation

Tags: ros, simulation, rviz, frame, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm new to tf and rviz. I have a simulation in stage with an array of lasers and robots. I want to see all laser scans in rviz but, as far as i know, i need to have a correct tree of frames (related between them), but simulating that, i have frame for every position model, but don't have a /world frame in which other frames can be related and connected.

Is there a way in which i could add a /world frame and parent it with another frames?

**EDIT:**

these are the frames I get: [frames.pdf](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/36103430/frames.pdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56045//world-frame-in-stage-simulation/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What transforms are you getting?

```
$ rosrun tf tf_monitor
```

Stage [should be providing](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage#tf_transforms_provided) transforms to the **/odom** frame.

Can **rviz** display them in **/odom**?

**EDIT**: I see stage is providing separate **/robot_N/odom** frames. That is actually reasonable, since neither is presumed to be exact.

If you wish to display them as if the **odom** frames were ground truth, you can define static transforms from **/map** to **/robot_N/odom**:

```
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /robot_0/odom 1000
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /robot_1/odom 1000
```

That is not really correct, since there should be a certain amount of noise added to your simulated odometry. But it should work well enough for viewing in the **/map** frame.

A more accurate solution would involve writing your own transform broadcaster that subscribes to the stage [base_pose_ground_truth topic](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage#Published_topics), broadcasting the exact pose in some convenient frame of reference. That may be tricky to get working.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-02-22**:
I have transforms /robot_0/odom through /robot_n/odom

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-02-23**:
Thanks Jack!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started with tf today and [this tf tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) helped me understand it and I would guess you need exactly that

All you need to do is create a link between every robot and the world frame

```
tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
tf::Transform transform;
transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(x,y,z)); // position in respect to the world frame
transform.setRotation( tf::Quaternion(x,y,z,w) ); // orientation in respect to the world frame
br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "world", "robot_n"));
```

This assumes you can somehow get an absolute pose from any robot in respect to the world frame. If you only get relative measurements between the robots, you do not need a world frame and create the transform broadcaster between robot_n and robot_m.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-02-23**:
Thanks for your answer. As you said, I could create a transform between robots, but the frames would be relative to a only robot. Instead of that i would like to have a fixed frame for all robots to relate to